# How can I show a detailed data by touching an UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating a catalog of products, and every product is an `UICollectionViewCell` with a `titleLabel`, an `UIImage` and a button. I want to show the product details when the button is touched but I don't know how to tell to every cell which product belongs

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I created an object with every object that the datasource array brings me but I need to link every object to its corresponding cell

Comment: add the relevant code and description to your question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to implement UICollectionViewDelegate's method and pass corresponding product by index.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Product *selectedProduct = self.products[indexPath.row];
    DetailsViewController *detailsVC = [[DetailsViewController alloc] initWithProduct:selectedProduct];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsVC animated:YES];
}
```

assuming you have declared property for your products;

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *products;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah! this might work, but when exactly the delegate calls that method? I have to add a gesture recognizer or something like that?

Comment: It Worked! thanks, I have to delete the button and it worked 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: you don't have to add gesture recognizers, this method get called every time you select an item/cell once you set collectionView's delegate